# Can delayed_jobs create delayed_jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm trying to figure out if I'm able to use `delayed_job`. I would need the ability to add jobs to the queue within a `delayed_job` `perform` method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, they can:

model `Machine`:

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base
  def perform
    Delayed::Job.enqueue Secondary.create!
  end
end
```

model `Secondary`:

```
class Secondary < ActiveRecord::Base
  def perform
    logger.info("Inside secondary's perform method (WIN)")
    Proof.create!
  end
end
```

from the console:

> Delayed::Job.enqueue Machine.create!

This ends up creating an instance of `Proof` and logs "Inside secondary's...".

Comment: My delayed job also works fine at kicking off another delayed job as part of its operation.

Comment: Yes, they absolutely can. There are some circumstances where it's useful to "chain" jobs like this, but most of the time you can just have a single job that transitions the state of a model as it goes so that the job can be restarted at the current point in its workflow if it fails.

Answer (score -1):

My simple test calling `send_later` in a method invoked by `send_later` indicates that *NO*, it will not work.

Comment: Perhaps it's just `send_later` that does not allow this. I tested in script/console.